# Insert Row after first occurence of partial String

Tags: vba, excel

I am working with a variably lengthed weekly report. The columns are fixed but the number of rows changes. I need to format it so that different categories are separated by blank lines. On Each column that contains data to be separated I have code that finds a the first appearance of a string of text and then inserts two or three rows above it.

This has worked until I get to a section of data that is identified by the phrase "DO NOT BUY". "DO NOT BUY" is then followed (in the same cell) by 
"-*reason we're not buying*".

As I still want all do not buys grouped together, I need something that pulls just the first part of the string. I have tried to adapt my current solution to utilize the left function (Find first occurrence where Left(Columns.AB:AB,10)="DO NOT BUY" and then insert row)   but I can't figure out how to make Left loop through the whole column rather than one cell...

Below is the code I have currently for finding and inserting rows.

```
Sub InsertBeforeGS()
Dim FindString As String
Dim rng As Range
FindString = "GS"
If Trim(FindString) <> "" Then
    With ActiveSheet.Range("AB:AB")
        Set rng = .Find(What:=FindString, _
                        After:=.Cells(.Cells.Count), _
                        LookIn:=xlValues, _
                        Lookat:=xlWhole, _
                        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                        SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
                        MatchCase:=False)
        If Not rng Is Nothing Then
            Application.GoTo rng, True
            ActiveCell.EntireRow.Insert
ActiveCell.EntireRow.Insert
ActiveCell.EntireRow.Insert
        Else
        End If
    End With
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Can you post any code or other things you have tried so far?  You can set a range, and have VBA loop through that with `For each cel in rng` (see [this page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/Aa221353(v=office.11).aspx) for some more info on looping).

Comment: Which column does do not buy occur?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Sub insert()

Dim lastRow As Long
Dim done As Boolean

'change A to the longest column (most rows)
lastRow = ActiveSheet.Cells(ActiveSheet.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

For i = 1 To lastRow
    'change the 1 below to the necessary column (ie, use 4 for column D)
    If Left(Cells(i, 1), 10) = "DO NOT BUY" Then
    Rows(i).insert
    done = True
    i = i + 1
    End If
    If done = True Then Exit For
Next

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks! This works perfectly in targeting the first string but I need it to before the first occurrence only. This inserts rows after every occurrence of "DO NOT BUY"

Comment: Wait. If you only need to insert one row, why use macro. Just manually search from top and insert it...

Comment: Perfect. Thank you for the help!

Comment: Just to answer your question, this is one step in one large series of code that formats a report varied length (but often as large as 3000 rows). There is a standard way that we format it but it has been, until now, manual and can take anywhere from 10-40 minutes. I am trying to automate as many steps as possible so other people can use it easily.